# how to print first word from a string with multiple words without space?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, string

I have a shell script to print appimage filenames inside a folder like this

```
#! /bin/bash

Dir="$HOME/Applications/"
Dir2="$HOME/Downloads/"

cd -P "$Dir"
for f in *.AppImage; do
z=$(echo $f | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
  echo $z
done
```

now the output is like this :

```
Altus-4.8.5-x86_64.AppImage
GitHubDesktop-linux-3.2.0-linux1.AppImage
webamp-desktop-0.3.0-x86_64.AppImage
YTDownloader.AppImage
```

I want the output to be like following:

```
Altus
GitHubDesktop-linux
webamp-desktop
YTDownloader
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Biggest problem here is defining exactly what a "word" is. On a quick look, I'd have expected any non-letter to terminate the word, but based on `webamp-desktop-0.3.0` -> `webamp-desktop`, that's not enough. What should happen if the input is something like `thingy3-desktop-1.2.3.AppImage`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I meant by "word" the lingual meaning of it " some letters but together and have a meaning" so webamp-desktop-0.3.0 are consisting of two words "webamp"&"desktop" and some numbers

Comment: yes, but that doesn't fly with a computer :) You need to be specific. Note that your description contradicts what you asked earlier, since if `webamp-desktop-0.3.0` is two words and some numbers, then the output containing just the first word should likely be just `webamp`. Of course if looking for `-0` (with any digit) works, then that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%` to remove suffixes:

```bash
for f in *.AppImage; do
  f=${f%.AppImage}
  echo "${f%%-[0-9]*}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` (and it's assumed no newline character in the file's name):

```
printf '%s\n' "$fileName" |
sed -E 's/(-[0-9].*)?\.AppImage//'
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Using GNU `grep`:

```
<INTPUT> | grep -oP '^\D+(?=-\d|\.)'
```

##### Using `Perl`:

```
<INPUT> | perl -nE 'say $& if /^\D+(?=-\d|\.)/'
```

##### Output

```
Altus
GitHubDesktop-linux
webamp-desktop
YTDownloader
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `^\D+` | Match 1 or more non-digit characters at the beginning of the regex |
| `(?=-\d|\.)` | Perform a lookahead, attempting to match a hyphen and a number, or a period, but do not include it in the selection. |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of your file names contain newlines then using any awk:

```
printf '%s\n' *.AppImage | awk -F'[.]|-[0-9]' '{print $1}'
```

If they can contain newlines then using GNU awk or any other version that can use NUL for the RS:

```
printf '%s\0' *.AppImage | awk F'[.]|-[0-9]' 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\0"} {print $1}'
```